# How do i setState with hooks of an object which has multiple arrays ? How to setdebtors here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am deleting an one id in an array, how do I setState after filtering it here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1m2qn

```
 const Debtors = () => {
      const debtors = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "John",
          relation: "friend",
          statement: [
            { id: 1, date: 2010, amount: "1000", purpose: "John" },
            { id: 2, date: 2014, amount: "2000", purpose: "john" }
          ]
        },   
,
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Jack",
      relation: "Friend",
      statement: [
        { id: 1, date: 2010, amount: "1000", purpose: "jack" },
        { id: 2, date: 2014, amount: "2000", purpose: "jack" }
      ]
    }  


      ];


  const [newDebtors, setdebtors] = React.useState(debtors);

  const handleDelete = (stat, i) => {
    const newList = newDebtors[0].statement.filter(x => x.id !== stat.id);

// How to set debtors here ?
   // setdebtors({ ...newDebtors, statement[0]: newList }); 
  console.log(newList)
```

// How to set debtors here ?

Comment: You're always changing statement of zeroth index ? is that you want ?

Comment: I have dynamically set the index in my full code, after selecting the id, I just dont know how to setState when there is array, can u pls give example of any index statement

Comment: can you just tell me the format of the new state that you need to set it as ... I mean an example of the output you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems:

1) You are iterating off the original debtors object in your render, instead of the `newDebtors` state you created via `useState()`, which is why there does not appear to be any UI change.

You need: `newDebtors[0].statement.map`

2) You need to pass in the item index in your handleDelete() so it knows what item in the array to update. You can have the function do something like this:

In the onClick:

```
 <a
   href="javascript:;"
   onClick={() => handleDelete(stat, i, 0)}
 >
```

In the handleDelete():

```
  const handleDelete = (stat, i, arrayIndex) => {
    const updatedDebtors = newDebtors.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === arrayIndex) {
        return {
          ...item,
          statement: item.statement.filter(
            statement => statement.id !== stat.id
          )
        };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });

    setDebtors(updatedDebtors);
  };
```

See sandbox for full solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-x7uoh

Comment: @LostCause you're welcome. I also added another component in there called FullSolution, which I think is what you ultimately will be looking for later on.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like that:

```
setdebtors((prevState) => {
  let newArray = Array.from(prevState);    // Copy the array
  // Manipulate the array as you wish
  return newArray;                         // return it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are mutating the array of "debtors" you need to map through the array of debtors and change any properties in the object.

```
const handleDelete = (stat, i) => {
const newList = newDebtors.map((debtor, i) => {
  if (i === 0) {
    debtor.statement = debtor.statement.filter(x => x.id !== stat.id);
  }
  return debtor;
});
setdebtors(newList);};
```

An even better approach is to use "useReducer" which is used for mutating more complex pieces of state, like you have here. THe docs are very helpful [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I dont know what exactly you are trying to do, 
Is this what you are looking for?

```
const handleDelete = (stat, i) => {
    const newList = newDebtors[0].statement.filter(x => x.id !== stat.id);
    const newFirstItem = {...newDebtors[0],statement: newList}
    const newDebtorList = newDebtors.filter(x => x.id !== newFirstItem.id);
    newDebtorList.unshift(newFirstItem);
    setdebtors(newDebtorList); 
}
```

I know this seems complex but you kinda actually need to do this as you cannot mutate an array in the state...
What I did here is I first created a new statement list(newList), then created a newFirstItem to be set as the new newDebtors[0], then created a new array(newDebtorList) of all the elements of newDebtors except the first one, I modified this array by pushing the newFirstItem to the 0th position(using unshift)
Finally updated the state with this new array...
hope it helps :)

Note: this is for changing the 0th element if you have the id please change the code accordingly